# Is it possible to have same name on two components?

Tags: c#, wpf, variables

I am doing a project where I need a timer with drop shadow. I managed to figure out a way to do the drop shadow with 2 labels, but my problem now is that I need to give both the same name to act in the exact same way in all situation WITHOUT having duplicated code. Is this possible?

```
        <Grid>
            <Label  x:Name="time" MouseDoubleClick="time_MouseDoubleClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Old English Text MT"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="22" Content="00:00:00" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="1.5" Y="1"/>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label x:Name="time2"  MouseDoubleClick="time_MouseDoubleClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Old English Text MT"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="22" Content="00:00:00" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
```

This is how the code looks to make the drop shadow. Is there a way around this? Or is there a way like in HTML where I can define a "class" name?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need two labels. You need [`DropShadowEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Label Content="00:00:00">
  <Label.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect/>
  </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```

Comment: OH, there is actually one added! Thanks mate! +1

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you in actual fact need a drop-shaddow effect, another implementation to have two controls update based on the same property might lie in binding.

In the initialize method of the codebehind file set the DataContext.

```
DataContext = this;
```

Change your xaml to bind to a common string property.

```
  <Grid>
        <Label  x:Name="time" MouseDoubleClick="time_MouseDoubleClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Old English Text MT"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="22" Content="{Binding Time}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black">
            <Label.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="1.5" Y="1"/>
            </Label.RenderTransform>
        </Label>
        <Label x:Name="time2"  MouseDoubleClick="time_MouseDoubleClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Old English Text MT"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="22" Content="{Binding Time}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
```

(The content property now includes binding)

Ensure that you have a property in the codebehind to support the binding

```
public string Time {get;set;}
```

Your code-behind (.cs file) should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and your property should Raise the Event.

Then by changing the Time property, the XAML will automatically update.

Comment: Let's re-invent all WPF effects! :)